# What is a faster way of merging the values of this Python structure into a single dictionary?

Tags: python, data-structures, refactoring, performance

I've refactored how the merged-dictionary (`all_classes`) below is created, but I'm wondering if it can be more efficient.

I have a dictionary of dictionaries, like this:

```
groups_and_classes = {'group_1': {'class_A': [1, 2, 3],
                                  'class_B': [1, 3, 5, 7], 
                                  'class_c': [1, 2], # ...many more items like this
                                 },
                      'group_2': {'class_A': [11, 12, 13],
                                  'class_C': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
                                 }, # ...and many more items like this
                     }
```

A function creates a new object from `groups_and_classes` like this (the function to create this is called often):

```
all_classes = {'class_A': [1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13],
               'class_B': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9],
               'class_C': [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
              }
```

Right now, there is a loop that does this:

```
all_classes = {}
for group in groups_and_classes.values():
    for c, vals in group.iteritems():
        for v in vals:
            if all_classes.has_key(c):
                if v not in all_classes[c]:
                    all_classes[c].append(v)
            else:
                all_classes[c] = [v]
```

So far, I changed the code to use a `set` instead of a `list` since the order of the list doesn't matter *and* the values need to be unique:

```
all_classes = {}
for group in groups_and_classes.values():
    for c, vals in group.iteritems():
        try:
            all_classes[c].update(set(vals))
        except KeyError:
            all_classes[c] = set(vals)
```

This is a little nicer, and I didn't have to convert the sets to lists because of how `all_classes` is used in the code.

**Question**: Is there a more efficient way of creating `all_classes` (aside from building it at the same time `groups_and_classes` is built, and changing everywhere this function is called)?

Comment: Is that the biggest bottleneck of you program that it needs optimizing? Those micro-optimizations are rarely needed. If, however, you do - the fastest way would be to code it in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a tweak for conciseness, though I'm not sure about performance:

```
from collections import defaultdict
all_classes = defaultdict(set)
for group in groups_and_classes.values():
    for c, vals in group.iteritems():
        all_classes[c].update(set(vals))
```

Defaultdicts are not quite the greatest thing since sliced bread, but they're pretty cool. :)

Comment: The problem with defaultdicts IMO is that whenever you reference a key that isn't in it, that key is added to the dict even if you were just getting the value associated with that key (empty set in this case) rather than setting the key to a value.

Comment: Combining @Brian's suggestion below with this solution, it is the fastest out of the 3 (mine and The Machine Charmer being the other 2)

Comment: @justin - good point. In my use case, I convert the defaultdict to a dict, so that it won't cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that might improve things slightly is to avoid the redundant conversion to a set, and just use:

```
all_classes[c].update(vals)
```

`update` can actually take an arbitrary iterable, as it essentially just iterates and adds, so you can avoid an extra conversion step.

Answer (score 2):

[**Combining Dictionaries Of Lists In Python**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495510/combining-dictionaries-of-lists-in-python).

```
def merge_dols(dol1, dol2):
    result = dict(dol1, **dol2)
    result.update((k, dol1[k] + dol2[k]) for k in set(dol1).intersection(dol2))
    return result

g1 = groups_and_classes['group_1']
g2 = groups_and_classes['group_2']

all_classes = merge_dols(g1,g2)
```

> OR

```
all_classes = reduce(merge_dols,groups_and_classes.values())
```

--copied from [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495510/combining-dictionaries-of-lists-in-python/1495821#1495821)

If you get more than two groups then you can use `itertools.reduce`

```
all_classes = reduce(merge_dols,groups_and_classes.values())
```