# Merging two dicts using pandas

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pandas

I have 2 dicts which are as follows:

```
{
"states": 
         [
           {
             "status": "BV",  
             "median": 240.0 
            }, 
            {
             "status": "CORR", 
             "median": 720.0
            }, 
         ]
}
```

and

```
{
"diseases": [
    {
        "status": "BV",  
        "median": 100.0,
        "disease_name": "Lupus"
    }, 
    {
        "status": "BV", 
        "median": 128.0,
        "disease_name": "Pulmonary Arterial Hypertension"
    }, 
    {
        "status": "CORR", 
        "median": 321.0,
        "disease_name": "Pulmonary Arterial Hypertension"
    }, 
    {
        "status": "CORR",
        "median": 670.0,
        "disease_name": "Rheumatology"
    }
]
}
```

How would one go about merging the 2 dicts into one using pandas so that the output is as follows:

```
{
"states": 
        [
            {
                "status": "BV",
                "median": 240.0, 
                "drilldown": "BV"
            }, 
            {
                "status": "CORR",
                "median": 720.0,
                "drilldown": "CORR"
            }
        ],

"drilldown": 
        [
          {
            "name":"BV",
            "data":
                    [
                      {
                        "median": 100.0,
                        "disease_name": "Lupus"
                      },
                      {
                        "median": 128.0, 
                        "disease_name": "Pulmonary Arterial Hypertension"
                      }
                    ]        
          },               
          {
            "name":"CORR",
            "data":
                    [
                      {
                        "median": 321.0,
                        "disease_name": "Lupus"
                      },
                      {
                        "median": 670.0, 
                        "disease_name": "Rheumatology"
                      }
                  ]        
            }
          ]
}
```

i did try giving it a shot by iterating over the lists but it looks very hacky and is computationally expensive.Was wondering if there is a better way to do it with Pandas ?

Comment: why the downvote ? can i have a justification ??

Comment: It is much better to show your current code, instead of just showing input and output. This way you show that you do not intend to use stackoverflow as a code writing service and it is easier for us to understand the logic behind the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas `concat` and `merge` functions are not built for working on dicts, they are built for DataFrame and Series etc.

You may find help in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495510/combining-dictionaries-of-lists-in-python) existing question.

```
combined = {}
combined.update(d1)
combined.update(d2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **concat([list of dict])** or **merge([list of dict])** to get the desired result.

Comment: could you be a little more explicit ?